# Is it possible to run 2^[column number], without a for loop in R?

Tags: r

For example, say I wish to run

```
for(i in 1:(length(data))){
    vector[i] <- 2^i*data[i]
  }
```

Is there a way to run without a for loop / in tidyverse?

I have been looking into the `map` function in `purrr`, however, cannot see a way to do this where we are doing "2^i"

Thanks

Comment: Assuming that `data` is a vector: `2^seq_along(data) * data`?

Comment: Great! That's the one. Thanks.